# Vala (C#-like language) compiles to C?

Tags: c, gtk, vala

I'm a C# developer who stumbled across a new programming language for linux called vala. It has almost exactly the same syntax as C#, which is awesome. I never really was a big fan of Mono. This allows programmers to write GTK+ apps in a C# style language. My question is: Does vala get compiled into C?

Comment: Excellent language as ever made is VALA. Many languages has been created by nobody actually keeping the C standards. The only language wrapper VALA is promoting C finally. I hope VALA becomes famous so that we can have a huge community in VALA.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**Yes, Vala is compiled directly to C.** From the Vala homepage:

> *valac produces C source and header files from Vala source files as if you've written your library or application directly in C.* Using a Vala library from a C application won't look different than using any other GObject-based library. There won't be a vala runtime library and applications can distribute the generated C code with their tarballs, so there are no additional run- or build-time dependencies for users.

You can read more about it [here](http://live.gnome.org/Vala) (and also get tutorials, mailing lists, et cetera). It's quite an interesting project.

Answer (score 14):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vala_(programming_language)):

> Rather than being compiled directly to assembler or to an intermediate language, Vala is compiled to C which is then compiled with the platform's standard C compiler.

Answer (score 11):

As John and Chris pointed out, Vala does indeed get compiled to C.

In fact, you can see the generated C code by running the Vala compiler with the `-C` (or `--ccode`) flag.